# php foreach loop redundancy

Tags: php, function, redundancy

I am learning how to use PHP. I read a file content into an array and assign variable name for each index in the array.

For example:

    `$words = file("example.txt"); #each line of the file will have the format a, b, c , d`

```
foreach ($words in $word) {  
$content = explode(",", $word); #split a, b, c, d  
list($a, $b, $c, $d) = $content;  
do something  
}  

/* And now I want to read file, split the sentence and loop over the array again, but
 the last statement will do something else different:   */
foreach ($words in $word) {  
$content = explode(",", $word); #split a, b, c, d  
list($a, $b, $c, $d) = $content;  
do something else different  
}
```

What can I do to reduce this redundancy? As you can see, I cannot make a function because the last statement do something different to the array. But the process of reading file, splitting sentences, and assigning vars are the same

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you meant to type `foreach($words as $word)`, with "as" instead of "in", but that's just a minor thing compared to the question.

You can certainly reduce the redundancy by storing the results of the `explode` calls:

```
$lines = Array();
foreach($words as $word) {
    list($a,$b,$c,$d) = $lines[] = explode(",",$word);
    // do something here
}

foreach($lines as $line) {
    list($a,$b,$c,$d) = $line;
    // do something else
}
```

This way you don't have to `explode` the line again.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you're just going to work with $a, $b, $c and $d, and leave $content intact, just list $content again to do something else different.

```
foreach ($words in $word) {  
  $content = explode(",", $word); #split a, b, c, d  

  list($a, $b, $c, $d) = $content;
  // do something, and when you're done:

  list($a, $b, $c, $d) = $content;
  // do something else different.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's LOTS of variations. The tricky part is identifying the generic parts that can be abstracted away. Sometimes you make your code worse by trying to make it too generic. But here's a sample using anonymous functions.

```
function foo($filename, $func) {
    $words = file($filename);
    foreach ($words as $word) {
        $content = explode(",", $word);
        call_user_func_array($func, $content);
    }
}

foo('people.txt', function($a, $b, $c, $d) {
    echo "$a\n";
});

foo('people.txt', function($a, $b, $c, $d) {
    echo $b + $c;
});
```

you might also be intrested in [array_map](http://www.php.net/array_map), [array_walk](http://www.php.net/array_walk), and [array_reduce](http://www.php.net/array_reduce), although I personally don't feel theyre often better than a loop... php's foreach is pretty darn awesome.